# If a power series is everywhere convergent and I introduce a parameter, is that too everywhere convergent?

Tags: complex-analysis, convergence-divergence, power-series

The question is somewhat ambiguously given in the title but here it is again;

> Consider an everywhere convergent power series around $z_0$
>   $$
> f(z) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n(z-z_0)^n.$$
>   If I introduce a parameter $k$ is the power series
>   $$(f(z))^k = \left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n(z-z_0)^n\right)^k$$
>   also automatically everywhere convergent for any $k$? Can $k$ be any complex number or does this only hold for reals? (if it does hold!)

I presume the answer is yes since for any $z$, $f(z)$ is just "a number" so raising this to a power isn't going to change the convergence properties of the series, but I'd like it if somebody could confirm this for me.

Comment: What is $k$? A nonnegative integer? An integer? An arbitrary complex number?

Comment: @DanielFischer Hmm, I think I'll add that as part of the question.

Comment: Suppose $k=1/2$ and $f(x)=x$. Then the function of interest is $\sqrt{x}$, which can't be expressed as a power series in $x$.

Comment: Okay, next problem is that $$\Biggl(\sum_{n = 0}^\infty a_n (z- z_0)^n\Biggr)^k$$ is not in the form of a power series (if $k \notin \{0,1\}$). So what series should converge everywhere or not? Are you asking whether the Taylor series of $f(z)^k$ about $z_0$ - which exists if $f(z_0) \neq 0$, but in general not if $f(z_0) = 0$ - converges everywhere?

Comment: I guess what I mean is more like "is $f(z)^k$ just a number"? That is to say, if $f(z)$ can be expressed as an everywhere convergent power series, can I have something undefined if all I do is raise said power series to some parameter $k$?

Comment: The weirdness is not in $f(x)$ (the example I gave was just $f(x)=x$, after all) but in the (non-integer) exponentiation operation. But is that so surprising? To take a square root, for instance, requires that we pick between two possible values. A single-valued analytic function can't do that.